# Algorithms : What is the difference between A* and Jump Point Search?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I need to know why Jump Point Search is better than A* for path finding?

Comment: Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197894/how-does-jump-point-search-algorithm-work-and-why-is-it-so-efficient and for the implementation: https://github.com/ClintFMullins/JumpPointSearch-Java (similar question without answer: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639533/path-finding-algorithms-a-vs-jump-point-search?rq=1)

Comment: @RC. as you can, there was no answer there.

Comment: @ArunSubramanian yup I saw that

Comment: Saw that, there was no answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why Jump Point Search is better than A*, it is because, Jump Point Search algorithm does not evaluate all nodes like A* but rather "jumps" or skips over few nodes in the tree/graph. This ensures that fewer nodes are expanded and hence quickening up your algorithm's running time.

A detailed paper on this can be found [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~dharabor/data/papers/harabor-grastien-aaai11.pdf):